# counting weights of objects in arrayList java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to count the weights of the items in this array list of items. However it isnt adding up the items correctly? Can anyone see why this might be?

```
int totalWeight = 0;
for (Item i : items) {
    totalWeight = totalWeight + i.getWeight();
}
return totalWeight;
```

Comment: post more relevent code

Comment: It should. Have you verified that the weight is correct in the objects? Also, can the weight exceed 2147483647?

Comment: looks good, whats the problem

Comment: isn't adding up correctly? what do oyu mean by that? the code looks correct. maybe getWeight is not returning what you expect. or that totalweight overflows

Comment: This code is correct (given that `getWeight()` returns an `int` and not a `float`. Check for errors elsewhere ( `items` is empty, `getWeight` is returning 0, you are not using the value returned by this function...)

Comment: @SJuan76: i just edited my post to the correct number. I did indeed mean "billion". ;)

Answer (score -1):

Please provide code for `Item` class. it may look like this:

```
public class Item {
    public Item(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    int weight;
}
```

usage:

```
ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
// add something here

int totalWeight = 0;

for(Item i: items){
    totalWeight = totalWeight + i.getWeight();
}
```

Comment: This wont compile and isn't an answer to his question.

Comment: @Izmaki of course it won't compile, it was a suggestion on how the Item class should look and how to use it